# URLEncode in java, decode in ruby

Tags: java, ruby, escaping, url-encoding

I have encoded a string to pass in a url using Java, I need to decode it in Ruby.
It mostly works except that I still have the plus signs and special characters like a hyphen do not get decoded.
I used URLEncoder.encode(myString) to encode
I used URI.unescape(my_string) to decode

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You'd get (better) answers if you included a sample string as encoded by URLEncoder, how it appears after URI.unescape, and finally what you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks guys for the reply, here's how I encode : URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8"); in Java, in this case url = "Le Point–" , in ruby after using : URI.unescape(url) I get "Le+Point\0096"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'cgi'
p str = CGI::unescape("%27A+dash+looks+like+this%3A+-+%27")
#=> "'A dash looks like this: - '"
```